# Getting Value from javascript using php preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to get value from javascript with php preg_match, but not quite sure how can i do that .

I want  `"/cusa/includeFile.action?productOverviewCid=0901e024801e6aba&componentCid=0901e024800bef11&userSelectedModel=0901e024801e6aba"`

which come between `"tabSpecifications"` and `, "Specifications"`

here what i am trying to do, but not working.

```
$file = '
<script type="text/javascript">
            tabCls.push(
                new pageModelTab(
                "tabSpecifications"
                , "/cusa/includeFile.action?productOverviewCid=0901e024801e6aba&componentCid=0901e024800bef11&userSelectedModel=0901e024801e6aba"
                , "Specifications"
                , 3
                , false
                , ""
                , null
                , true
                , null
                )
                );
        function onClick_tabSpecifications() {
                try {
                var location = new String(window.location);
                if (location && location.indexOf("?selectedName") != -1) {
                return true;
                }
        new TabState("3").addTabToBrowserHistory();
                show("3");
                showHideFooterDisclaimer(\'Specifications\');
                return false;
                } catch (e) {
                //alert(e.message);
                return true;
                }
        }
            </script>';


preg_match("/^cusa/", $file );
```

i just start basics of preg_match ...

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me -

```
$pattern = '/(\/cusa\/).*/';
preg_match($pattern, $file, $match);
print_r($match);
```

[EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/hifq-5nkm)

If you want to add to the search parameters (as asked in your comment) do this -

```
$pattern = '/(\/cusa\/includeFile.action).*/';
```

Comment: Thx for help ... i was wondering can i find 'cusa/includeFile.action' value instead of cusa  ... Please help